# Scala - gui application does not exit

Tags: scala, user-interface, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a very simple GUI app in Scala/IntelliJ:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val frame = new JFrame()
    frame.setSize(900, 700)
    frame.setVisible(true)

    //THis is probably not necessary
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter {
      override def windowClosed(e: WindowEvent) {
        System.exit(0)
      }
    })

  }
```

Firstly, the windowAdapter code is not invoked when I close the window... Secondly, when I close the window , the app is still running and I have to stop it from the intellij console. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Why dont u use a [MainFrame](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.swing.MainFrame)?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of a JFrame when closing is HIDE_ON_CLOSE which does specifically what it says. That's why your event isn't getting fired : because the window isn't really closed. You can deal with this by changing the default closing behavior of your frame with :

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

You can also change your event with windowClosing. See java doc :

> Invoked when the user attempts to close the window from the window's
>   system menu.

Or you can simply get rid of your listener and add :

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```